# Problems copying some but not all mp3 files from external drive

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, mp3

When moving from my old Vista pc to my new Win 8.1 PC.

I am facing problems copying data. I have moved all my audio books to an NTFS formatted external usb drive and the problem is that when copying SOME of the files I get an error saying can not read from source or destination file. This can effect 4 of 5 files / chapters / tracks of the same audio book and its no logic. I have taken ownership of the drive from the root level.

This is driving me crazy and ruining my new pc experience.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your moving away from Vista a bit too late in my opinion.

I would run some file system tools on the drive to check for file system issues. Hopefully it can repair them.

On another note, it may be about to die and best not to rely on this disk anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your tip - I will try disk repair. Regarding late moving away from Vista, I am actually helping a family member :-) My wife and kids are all running 8.1 on their laptops and surface devices.